# How do I make both VS and Angular-cli happy with a TypeScript typings reference?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm working on an Angular 4 project and I want to use `ng2-charts`.

I followed the instructions on https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/ however their instructions are unclear or lacking detail about how to install the package correctly, for example it says:

> Important: Embedding Chart.js in application is mandatory!
>
> ```
> <script src="node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js"></script>
> ```

I put this `<script>` element in my `index.html` file but it didn't work becuse I got 404 errors from the `ng serve` webserver command.

Eventually I found this page: https://alligator.io/angular/chartjs-ng2-charts/ which explained that I actually need to list `Chart.min.js` inside my `.angular-cli.json` file's `scripts: []` array, phew!

I now have charts working in my Angular project, however I want to use TypeScript typings files so I can have strongly-typed data-bound properties in my Angular component `.ts` source.

I ran `npm install @types/chartjs --save` - which is this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/chartjs which provides the definitions of `interface ChartDataSet`, `interface ChartSettings`, and so on.

My `Component` looks like this:

```
@Component( { ... } )
export class FooComponent {

    public chartData: Partial<ChartDataSet>[] = [
        { label: "Foo", data: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] },
        { label: 'Bar', data: [ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ] }
    ];

    public chartOptions: Partial<ChartSettings> = {
        responsive: true
    };
}
```

When I run `ng serve` I got this compilation error:

> ERROR in C:/git/project/appmodule/foo.component.ts (32,33): Cannot find name 'ChartDataSet'.
>   ERROR in C:/git/project/appmodule/foo.component.ts (37,33): Cannot find name 'ChartSettings'.

After some research and experimentation, I manually added the typings file to my `src/tsconfig.app.json` file:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "files": [
      "../node_modules/@types/chartjs/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

I don't like this - it feels like I'm doing something wrong, but it does work and `ng serve` builds the project successfully.

However, now Visual Studio 2017 (with TypeScript 2.5.2) complains inside my `foo.component.ts` file:

```
(TS) Cannot find name 'ChartDataSet'.
(TS) Cannot find name 'ChartSettings'.
```

I thought I'd fix this by adding this line to the top of `foo.component.ts`:

```
/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/@types/chartjs/index.d.ts" />
```

But this surprisingly had no effect.

I also tried each of these:

```
import * as c from '@types/chartjs';
import * as c from '@types/chartjs/index';
import * as c from '@types/chartjs/index.d.ts';
```

In all cases, TypeScript complained about `index` not being a module.

I saw that from within Visual Studio, TypeScript uses `tsconfig.json` instead of `tsconfig.app.json`, so I added the "index.d.ts`entry to`tsconfig.json` (as above) however when I did this it completely broke TypeScript within Visual Studio and it I had many error messages like

```
(TS) Cannot find module '@rxjs/Observable'.
(TS) Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
(TS) Cannot find name 'module'.
etc...
```

Comment: Try `import {ChartDataSet, ChartSettings} from 'chartjs';` (Without modifying _tsconfig_ and adding `/// <reference...`)

Comment: @AlekseyL The `import { ChartDataSet } from 'chartjs'` gives me the error "(TS) File [...]/chartjs/index.d.ts' is not a module.".
"

Comment: Sorry, tried it also now - seems that typings are broken (nothing is exported, that's why it is not recognized as a module)

Comment: @AlekseyL. Thank you for the hint. I opened the `node_modules/@types/chartjs/index.d.ts` file and changed `interface` to `export interface` in the `chartjs.d.ts` file and it magically worked, I could even remove the `"files"` array from my `tsconfig.app.json` file. However my changes to this file are not permanent. How can I make it permament?

Comment: Got it working without modifying original typings with just `import {} from 'chartjs';` **I have no idea why this working.. By the way you can use chart.js without listing it in _.angular-cli.json/scripts_ - you can just use `import Chart from 'chart.js';`